# Notification in Android when a json api endpoint gets new values

Tags: android, firebase, service, background

I have a json api endpoint which provides json data of news. I want to send notification or create notification to all user when new news are updated. I have looked through several aspects like background service and fcm.

But I want it automated like every time the news is updated the user gets notification. Either by creating webservice by node.js using fcm api endpoint or background service which checks for update and create a notification on news update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually needs [cron service](https://github.com/firebase/functions-cron). Our service is very similar with your question, we have a feature which send notification when some delivery is arrived to the destination. We uses third party tracking service which provides REST API to check shipping status.

We approached it as how Firebase team [recommended](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html).

It is working perfectly but one thing you should be careful is **how often you want to send notification to users?**

If you want realtime receiving data from 3rd party endpoint, the server should have `push` service to your Cloud Functions for Firebase instead of `cron service`.

You would know what is [pull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_technology) and [push](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) in computer networking system.

If you don't need realtime receiving, you can set your cron schedule as densely or lazily depends on your needs.

Sending FCM from Cloud Functions for Firebase is too easy, so I won't mention it.

Comment: Thanks. And is it a paid service?

Comment: @AbhishekPathak Yes. If you wanna save money, u can run cron service with your pc or you can also use raspberry pi.

Comment: @AbhishekPathak I would be thankful if you accept my answer if it was helpful to you.